# Why doesn't my application.ontime work in an if statement? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an application.ontime routine like the following.

```
Sub timer()

If Hour(Time) <= 15 Or Hour(Time) >= 22 Then

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K5"), Procedure:="dataextract", Schedule:=False

    On Error GoTo 0

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K5") = Now + TimeSerial(0, WorksheetFunction.Floor(Minute(Now), 5) + 5 - Minute(Now), 1 - Second(Now))

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K5"), Procedure:="dataextract", Schedule:=True

End If


End Sub
```

I want this routine to run between 10pm on `day 0` to 4pm on `day 1`, and then restart on its own on 10pm on `day 1` to 4pm on `day 2`, and so on. The code stops at 4pm but does not restart itself at 10pm. As you can see, I don't ever turn `schedule:=false` so I don't understand why it doesn't restart..?

Comment: `Timer` already has a built-in VBA meaning. Perhaps change the name. I doubt that this is the issue, but it might be.

Comment: What is the interval you're shooting for? Not sure I follow your use of TimeSerial here.  And how does `timer` get called?  There's nothing here which would restart the code once it's been stopped. i.e. if `timer` is called after 3pm and before 10pm then no action is taken and no other run is scheduled.

Comment: I'm calling it every 5 minutes. The floor function just rounds the first run to to the next 5 minute interval. E.g., I start application at 9:43pm, it will run at 9:45pm. I also check to make sure there is only 1 instance of application.ontime running.

Comment: Can you think of a way that would allow it to restart again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure I made a mistake in here somewhere but you should get the idea...

```
Sub timer()

    Const PROC As String = "dataextract"
    Const INTV_MIN As Long = 5

    Dim rTime As Range

    Set rTime = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K5")

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=rTime.Value, Procedure:=PROC, Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Hour(Time) <= 15 Or Hour(Time) >= 22 Then
        '5min from now
        rTime.Value = Now + TimeSerial(0, _
                        WorksheetFunction.Floor(Minute(Now), INTV_MIN) + INTV_MIN - Minute(Now), _
                        1 - Second(Now))
    Else
        '10pm today
        rTime.Value = Date + TimeSerial(22, 0, 0)
    End If
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=rTime.Value, Procedure:=PROC, Schedule:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: If the `Timer` Procedure is called by the `dataextract` procedure then these lines are not needed: `On Error Resume Next` `Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=rTime.Value, Procedure:=PROC, Schedule:=False` `On Error GoTo 0`. Also as previously mentioned by John it's suggested to change the name of the procedure as [Timer is a VBA Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264416(v=office.15).aspx)